# What happens when the switch flow table is full?

Tags: mininet, openflow, openvswitch, onos

What if flow table is full in ovs and flow entry cannot be added??

What message does the switch send to the controller through openflow??

I installed it with mininet and openvswitch. Where can I find the openvswitch code?

I am currently using the openflow 1.3 version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that can help you to solve your problems is to install "Wireshark" tool and capture packets that exchanging between OpenFlow controller and switches.

After installing Wireshark select Any for the interface and start capturing, you can use "openflow_v4" for filter OpenFlow packets.

Then check for any error in the body of OpenFlow packets.